# can python's list method `index()` find a list element in a list

Tags: python, indexing

**update 0**

My test code was very naive and I have to enhance it as follows ...

```
n=2
times=intervals([9,30],[11,30])
u=[]
v=[]

for t in times:
    u+= [[t[0],t[1]]]
    for i in range(0,n):
       t.append("")
    t[3]=3
    v+=[t]
    print "t:",t

print "v:",v

print "u.index:",u.index([10, 30])
```

... so from my test code I need to use the value of variable `v` for variable `times` and I need to use the result of `u.index([10, 30])` for my index. BrenBarn finally got through to me, I hope.

My test code that follows ...

```
n=2
times=intervals([9,30],[11,30])
for t in times:
    for i in range(0,n):
       t.append("")
    t[3]=3
    print t
```

... produces the following print result

```
[9, 30, '09:30AM', 3, '']
[10, 0, '10:00AM', 3, '']
[10, 30, '10:30AM', 3, '']
[11, 0, '11:00AM', 3, '']
```

Can the `index()` method be used to find, for example, the index in list `t` of the "element" [10, 30, ... ]?  Or do I need to construct the integer list `[930,100,1030,110]` and index() that list, instead? Or are there other suggestions?

Comment: Your list `t` in this code is actually just one of the individual lists. Do you mean searching the list of lists, as @BrenBarn's answer does?

Comment: From your comment on my answer, it's still not clear what you want.  You say you want to do `t.index([10, 30])`, but what do you want this to return?  Do you really want `t.index` or do you want `times.index`?

Comment: @BrenBarn I guess I do really want times.index() and your answer gave me the  way to get it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you even try it, or am I misunderstanding your question?

```
>>> t = [[9, 30, '09:30AM', 3, ''],
... [10, 0, '10:00AM', 3, ''],
... [10, 30, '10:30AM', 3, ''],
... [11, 0, '11:00AM', 3, '']]
>>> t.index([10, 30, '10:30AM', 3, ''])
2
```

Comment: BrenBarn, No, I have not tried it, but when I tried `print t.index([10, 30, '10:30AM', 3, ''])`, I got `ValueError: [10, 30, '10:30AM', 3, ''] is not in list`. Did you really try it and have it work, or is your code just pseudocode? Or did I implement it incorrectly? Anyhow, in my case I would want to supply only `print t.index([10, 30])` because I would not know the other values. Thanks.

Comment: However, when I put `u =[]` in front of the for.loop and `u+= [[t[0],t[1]]]` inside the outer for.loop, then `print u.index([10, 30])` produced the correct index, 2. So yes, your idea does work.